# CSS3 Multi column containing divs and sections

Tags: html, css, css-multicolumn-layout

So I just found out about css3 `columns` specification and immediately saw that I can use it to "modernize" [my forum listing](http://www.loganyoung.za.net/forum) which uses a dynamically generated table.

The code to generate the table is quite complex as it determines itself whether or not to place the next database row's data into a new row in the table or into a new column. Using the css3 columns way, I assume that I can simply let the code read the data into the page and leave css3 to decide what's supposed to go into which column.

I've come across a bit of a problem though. When using it, the content isn't split across the specified number of columns.

Here's some code for reference:

```
.2col {
    column-count: 2;
    column-width: 400px;
    column-gap: 10px;
    column-rule: 1px solid #e1e1e1;
}


<div class="cats 2col">
    <div class="title">
        <div class="t">
            <h2><a href="#" class="sh" id="t1">-</a> Title 1</h2>
        </div>
        
        <section>
            <div class="cat">
                <p>Category 1<span>This is the first category</p>
            </div>
            
            <div class="cat">
                <p>Category 2<span>This is the second category</p>
            </div>
            
            <div class="cat">
                <p>Category 3<span>This is the third category</p>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
    
    <div class="title">
        <div class="t">
            <h2><a href="#" class="sh" id="t1">-</a> Title 2</h2>
        </div>
        
        <section>
            <div class="cat">
                <p>Category 1<span>This is the first category</p>
            </div>
            
            <div class="cat">
                <p>Category 2<span>This is the second category</p>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
</div>
```

I set up this JSFiddle for testing: http://jsfiddle.net/LYoung/JLVEs/1/

Clearly I'm doing something wrong. Can anyone help me identify what that is and why it's wrong?

Comment: A note: Unless you're using only IE10 you have to add the vendor before the css rules, like this: `-webkit-colum-*` See caniuse.com: "[Can I use CSS3 Multiple column layout?](http://caniuse.com/multicolumn)".

Comment: Nice tip, however, I added in the -webkit- prefix to my css class on the jsfiddle and didn't see any new developments there. It seems to have been ineffective

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found two problems in your example :

- First the -webkit and -moz rules
- And the 2col name for your class

I tried in JSFiddle renaming your 2col class for twoCol and adding the -webkit and -moz rules and it seemed to work ([Fiddle Example here](http://jsfiddle.net/JLVEs/14/))

There is still some problems with the style but it splits the content in two columns when the window is large enough

```
    <div class="cats twoCol">
    <div class="title">
        <div class="t">
            <h2><a href="#" class="sh" id="t1">-</a> Title 1</h2>
        </div>

        <section>
            <div class="cat">
                <p>Category 1<span>This is the first category</p>
            </div>

            <div class="cat">
                <p>Category 2<span>This is the second category</p>
            </div>

            <div class="cat">
                <p>Category 3<span>This is the third category</p>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>

    <div class="title">
        <div class="t">
            <h2><a href="#" class="sh" id="t1">-</a> Title 2</h2>
        </div>

        <section>
            <div class="cat">
                <p>Category 1<span>This is the first category</p>
            </div>

            <div class="cat">
                <p>Category 2<span>This is the second category</p>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
</div>​

                body {
        background: #000;
    }
    .title {
        padding-bottom: 10px;
    }
.twoCol {
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    column-count: 2;
    -webkit-column-width: 400px;
    -moz-column-width: 400px;
    column-width: 400px;
    -webkit-column-gap: 10px;
    -moz-column-gap: 10px;
    column-gap: 10px;
    -webkit-column-rule: 1px solid #e1e1e1;
    -moz-column-rule: 1px solid #e1e1e1;
    column-rule: 1px solid #e1e1e1;
}
    h2 {
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 20px;
        color: #bede06;
    }
    .t {
        width: 800px;
        column-span: all;
    }
    .t a {
        color: #bede06;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 22px;
    }
    t:after {
        content: '';
        display: table;
    }
    .cat {
        color: #000;
        font-size: 18px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        box-shadow: 0 0 2px #b6bcc6;
        text-shadow: 2px 2px #fff;
        background-image: linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(225,225,225) 37%, rgb(255,255,255) 69%);
        background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(225,225,225) 37%, rgb(255,255,255) 69%);
        background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(225,225,225) 37%, rgb(255,255,255) 69%);
        background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(225,225,225) 37%, rgb(255,255,255) 69%);
        background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(225,225,225) 37%, rgb(255,255,255) 69%);

        background-image: -webkit-gradient(
            linear,
            left bottom,
            left top,
            color-stop(0.37, rgb(225,225,225)),
            color-stop(0.69, rgb(255,255,255))
    );
    }
    .cat {
        width: 400px;
        height: 50px;
        margin: 0 0 10px 10px;
        padding-left: 5px;
    }
    .cat span {
        display: block;
        font-style: italic;
        font-size: 14px;
    }​
```

Comment: Yes I see the columns work, thanks! Just one question though, why would `2col` be a bad class name?

Comment: Class names starting with a number are only understood by Internet Explorer.

Source : http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_id_class.asp

Answer (score 0):

```
section {
    position: relative;
    width: 450px;
    border:1px solid red;
    display:block;
}

dl.2col {
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
    column-count: 2;

    -moz-column-gap: 10px;
    -webkit-column-gap: 10px;
    column-gap: 10px;

    column-rule: 1px solid #e1e1e1;
}

dl.2col dd {
     -moz-column-width: 200px;
     -webkit-column-width: 200px;
     column-width: 200px; 
     display:inline-block ! important;
    float:none;
}​

<section>
<dl class="cats title 2col">
    <dd class="t"><h2><a href="#" class="sh" id="t1">-</a> Title 1</h2></dd>

    <dd class="cat">Category 1<span>This is the first category</span></dd>

    <dd class="cat">Category 2<span>This is the second category</span></dd>

    <dd class="cat">Category 3<span>This is the third category</span></dd>

    <dd class="t"><h2><a href="#" class="sh" id="t1">-</a> Title 2</h2></dd>

    <dd class="cat">Category 1<span>This is the first category</span></dd>

    <dd class="cat">Category 2<span>This is the second category</span></dd>
</dl>
</section>
```

​

Comment: Hi Carol, I thought I was never going to get any response here. Thanks for your suggestion. I can see where you're going with this, but applying it hasn't worked -> http://jsfiddle.net/LYoung/JLVEs/8/

Comment: Yeah, I can't figure out why it isn't working, but if you right click "inspect element" on the columns under the heading "Contact Directory" on this page you will see i managed to crack that nut there:

http://www.awri.com.au/contact/

Answer (score 0):

```
section dl.directory {
    margin-left:1em;
    margin-bottom:7px;
    -moz-column-count:2;
    -webkit-column-count:2;
    column-count:2;
    -moz-column-gap:7px;
    -webkit-column-gap:7px;
    column-gap:7px;
    -moz-column-rule:1px solid #D0D2D3;
    -webkit-column-rule:1px solid #D0D2D3;
    column-rule:1px solid #D0D2D3;
}

section dl.directory dd {
    display:inline-block;
    -moz-column-width:225px;
    -webkit-column-width:225px;
    column-width:225px;
    margin:0 5px;
    padding:5px 0;
    border-bottom:1px solid #D0D2D3;
}

section dl.directory dd em {
    font styling here
}
```